# What's the difference between navigating to Declaration, Type Declaration, Implementation in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, navigation

[The official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Navigation_from_Symbols.html)
 is unclear for me to extract the real difference between them.
Could someone give an example or scenario for the sake of easier understanding?

[image]

Comment: "Go to declaration" moves you to the place in code where variable is declared (e.g. String str= "Hello"). "Go to Type declaration" will move you to the class where variable type is declared (e.g. String.class). "Go to implementation" will move you to implementations if any, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#go_to_implementation

Comment: Could you explain which parts of [Go to Declaration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Declaration.html), [Go to Type Declaration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Type_Declaration.html), and [Go to Implementation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Implementation.html) are not clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following example code. Your cursor is at `m` in `m.aMethod();` or at `aMethod` in the same line.

Main.java

```
public class Main implements MyInterface {

  public static final void main(String args []) {
    MyInterface m = new Main();
//              ^1

    m.aMethod();
//  ^ Declarations will bring you to 1, the declaration of the variable (m)
//    Type Declaration will bring you to 2, the declaration of the type of the variable (MyInterface)
    m.aMethod();
//       ^ Declaration will bring you to 3, the declaration of the method in the type (MyInterface) of the variable
//         Implementation(s) will bring you to 4, the declaration of the method implementing the interface method
  }

  public void aMethod() {
//            ^4
  }
}
```

MyInterface.java

```
public interface MyInterface {
//               ^2
  public void aMethod();
//            ^3
}
```

Comment: sorry sir, but why are there *two* lines of  `m.aMethod();`   ?